# Identify a 24 pin QFP with the writing "024 14 09 SD426"

Tags: components, identification

I have these parts but I don't have any part number information for them.  They are 3x3mm, and the marking reads 024 14 09 SD426. I checked some online part finder sites but couldn't identify it.

[image: Photo]

Comment: The notch on the ground pad is very unconventional.  I could not find the manufacturer, but all I can tell you is that it is a 3x3 QFN package.  Those first few numbers are most likely production date and maybe lot information.

Comment: Where did you get it from and why are you asking? I doubt these will be very useful for anything except the original application.

Comment: These were sent to me by mistake from DigiKey.  So I doubt they are custom parts or ASICs.  They weren't sure what they were and just sent me the correct part.  I was curious to know if they were something I could use before tossing them out. The notch is not that uncommon, I've seen it on other parts.

Comment: Which part did you order?

Comment: It's got to be a Silabs IC of some form I would have thought. Only one out there I've found using a QFN24 3x3 package. The middle pad on each side is really odd - never seen anything like it. As an example [this](http://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm8lb1-datasheet.pdf) has the same pad arrangement (four corner pads), and [this](http://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2110.pdf) mentions the oddly notched thermal pad as a pin 1 marker. Neither are the correct IC, but Silabs are the closest to that sort of package.

Comment: We are not ChipWorks.

Comment: @BruceAbbott [this](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=FDMC8321LCT-ND) was the part I ordered.  Thanks 12Lappie and Tom for taking a look.